# This class is not a key value coding complaint while using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

Searching in textfield returning:

> [<__NSCFString 0x7c6513f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key H.

"H" is the letter which I typed in text field.

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
    // NSLog( @"text changed: %@", theTextField.text);
    if((theTextField.text).length!=0){
        isSearching=YES;

        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@",
                                    theTextField.text];

        searchResults=(NSMutableArray *)[_arrayTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];(getting exception here)
        [__tableview_addcontactview reloadData];
    }
    else{
        isSearching=NO;
        [__tableview_addcontactview reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your predicate format has 2 placeholders but only one variable to substitute for them.

Comment: As @PhillipMills said: `@"%K contains[c] %@"`: `%K` is a placeholder, `%@` is a placeholder. So there are two placeholders, but you give only one value `theTextField.text`.